# Create binary indicator dependent on previous row using Python and Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, data-manipulation, feature-extraction, feature-engineering

I am coming from the following Excel table:

[image]

I want to create a binary indicator indicating cases where the departure airport is not equal the previous arrival airport - basically reconstructing what I did in Excel (Note: "WENN" is equal to "IF" in English). The dataframe is sorted accordingly.
What is the best way to do this with python? Is there a way to solve it with pandas?

And lastly, is there a better and more concise technical formulation to ask this question?

Thanks already!

Comment: You may have a look at the [shift](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) method. If you shift your `arr_ap_shed` one pos further, then you can check for equality on the index basis against `dep_ap_shed`. This is a fairly simple example, but even so, please always add your mock data to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `shift` method as:

```
bin_indicator = df['arr_ap_shed'].shift(1).eq(df['dep_ap_shed'])
bin_indicator[0] = False  # first pos after `shift` is undefined
```

Comment: That worked, thank you!